# Can't manage to change text color on Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-styles

I've tried a lot of other answers on SO, none of them seem to work for me. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Here's my xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/product_category_spinner"
    android:theme="@style/AppartmentBlue" />
```

And here's my Java (it's a DialogFragment extending class):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_dialog, container, false);
    Spinner productCategory = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.product_category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_array));
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    productCategory.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    // setCancelable(false);
    return v;
}
```

The thing is, the text is white on very bright gray. It came that way by default, if it came in black foreground I wouldn't need to touch it. Why's it doing this? My theme extends from `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`.

I don't wanna set it at runtime, I'm gonna have a lot of spinners and I want it to be global across the app, with the option for me to add later themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps:

My Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_cat"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/left_margin_large"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Setting up the adapters:

```
private final int _singleItemRes = R.layout.simple_spinner_item;
private final int _dropdownRes = R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_handler.getContext(), _singleItemRes, getTitles());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(_dropdownRes);
```

simple_spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/left_margin_small"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin_small"
    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_text"/>
```

Let me know if I am missing anything from the answer and I will add it in.

Comment: I changed it to use my own style and it worked! Sad that I need to make a resource layout of plain TextViews just to change colors globally.

Comment: Glad it works. I agree it is annoying and not very well thought out from Google.